# Span inside button not clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button with a span to show a fa icon:

```
<button class="menu" onclick="showMenu()">
  <span class="fa fa-bars fa-1x"></span>
</button>
```

When I click on the button, the javascript function 'showMenu' gets executed. However, when I click on the fa icon (inside the button), the function does not get executed. From a look and feel, the fa icon really is/should be part of the button.

It seems, as only the padding area of the button around the fa icon and not the fa icon itself is sensitive to the clicking and executes the javascript function.

How can I have a button in HTML with a fa icon inside and where I can click anywhere inside the button and the function gets executed?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. As it stands, you have no content in the button at all, just an empty span that takes up no space.

Comment: Side note: You need to provide content to your button even if you don't want it visible. This is required for accessibility compliance.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jKBRbO  works fine with span click inside button , share your js code to debug issue correctly

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `click` event on the `button` will allow for the event to bubble up and be caught by the button when it is actually triggered by child elements.

But, of course, if an inline element, like a `span` element is empty, it occupies no space on the screen and so, if the event is attached to it, it can't be triggered.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  console.log("clicked on " + evt.target);
});
```

```css
button { width:100px; height:50px; }
```

```html
<button class="menu">
  <span class="fa fa-bars fa-1x">X</span>
</button>
```

Comment: *if*? Why *if*? The code in the question clearly attaches the event to the button, notice the `onclick="showMenu()"`, so there is no *if*. Because of that, I'm not sure this can be considered a correct answer to the question, although the provided info is correct with good explanation.